# sharepoint 2010 using SPDiag for performance troubleshooting

Tags: performance, troubleshooting, spdiag

I've installed SPDiag on the WFE server of the farm and have to troubleshoote performance issues on some pages. But not sure how to do this using SPDiag. The only screen I've found usefull for now is Peformance counters screen.